# $inc edit in place mongodb 3.2 wiredtiger

Tags: mongodb

Does any update on a document on mongodb 3.2 (wiredtiger) is always rewriting the full document on disk or can do partial update.

For instance, the $inc operation does really change the document BSON structure. If the field already exists, then the 4 bytes for the integer remains at the same position and we could just update the 4 bytes.

on which rule, an update with wiredtiger could be edited in place ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** The following is simplified for the sake of shortness and ease of understanding.

WiredTiger has a copy-on-write paradigm. On the other hand, documents are never fragmented. So if you modify it, it gets copied.

BUT: Documents are synced to disk every so often to create a snapshot. Every 60s by default, during which time durability is provided by the write ahead journal.
WiredTiger is highly efficient in doing the disc sync.

So between two snapshots, your `$inc` operations are written to the journal and applied to the in-memory representation of your document. Only when a new snapshot is created, the document actually is copied.

So basically *every* edit to a document is in place, and only during the creation of a snapshot the heavy lifting is done.

Comment: I endorse what Markus wrote above. However, MongoDB does write to journal almost instantaneously ( I believe it's 100ms) but serialization from journal to actually collection can take place much later.

Comment: Do you have the article related to atomic operation like $inc that describe in details hozw snapshot, journal works ?
Does wiredTiger compare to mmapv1 faster for doing $inc ?

Comment: @SébastienRichez You should start with the docs https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/storage/